# Unable to prevent query from SQL Injection in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, brakeman

I am working on a Rails project and using Brakeman as a tool for debugging. I have used a query to get data from table, but during Brakeman's test it states there is Sql Injection Possibility in the query.

Here is my query:

```
Applicant.all.where("profile_id=#{current_user.profile.id}").first
```

But I don't know what's the issue with this query, if it is not secured then how can I prevent it from SQL injections?

Comment: You've tagged MySQL and SQL Server, which one is it?

Comment: Try this Applicant.where('profile_id = ?', current_user.profile.id).first OR Applicant.where(profile_id: current_user.profile.id).first

Comment: Check this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions

Comment: phppgadmin is not a database. Its a admin screen for postgresql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

USE this according to rails guide right way to do this

```
Applicant.where('profile_id = ?', current_user.profile.id).first 

OR

Applicant.where(profile_id: current_user.profile.id).first

 OR

Applicant.find_by_profile_id(current_user.profile.id)

 OR

Applicant.find_by(profile_id: current_user.profile.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing that you're looking for is:

```
Applicant.find_by(profile_id: current_user.profile.id)
```

When you read this code it's easier to understand what you're doing.